# Music control with android and ubuntu desktop

Tags: bluetooth, android

Is there a application/synchronization (not entirely sure what I am supposed to look for) that makes it possible to play music on my ubuntu desktop and then change/pause/play it with my Android phone? 
Maybe something were I connect with bluetooth?

I am not looking for a while VNC or remote control just simple music play!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are quite a selection of Android remote controls for a popular music players running on Ubuntu.

#### Rhythmbox

- [Remotebox](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.raphaelbaron.remotebox&hl=en) on Google Play

  [image]
- [Rhythmote](http://www.joaomak.net/projetos/rhythmote) for download from the project's homepage

#### VLC

- See list of [remote application maintained by Videolan](https://wiki.videolan.org/Control_VLC_from_an_Android_Phone/)

#### XBMC/Kodi

- [Official remote application Kore](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.xbmc.kore&hl=en) from Google Play

  [image]

---

The remote applications vary considerably in their feature support. Which to choose depends a lot on personal requirements.

For me the combination of Kodi and it's remote app works very smooth, covers a lot of player controls, and has the nice feature of displaying cover art of tracks playing.

Comment: Give us screenshots =)

Comment: Nice, already upvoted :)